# How to read a CSV into list in Python

Tags: python

I have a file with the following structure

```
abc,def,[ghi,jkl],mno
```

and I would like to read the contents of the file into a list in Python, so that

```
list[0]=abc
list[1]=def
list[2]=[ghi,jkl] // I would like to be address the individual members of this sub-list list[2][0] and list[2][1]
list[3]=mno
```

Any ideas?

Thank you.

I have tried,

```
import csv

with open('file.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    data = list(reader)
```

But it returns a list of length=1.

Comment: `data` should be a list of lists. Each element is one row from the file, and the columns are elements of the nested lists.

Comment: So if `len(data) == 1` it means you have only 1 row in the CSV. `data[0][0]` will be `abc`.

Comment: You'll have to do something like ```data[0].split(",")```

Comment: @SurajShourie That won't work. `data[0]` is a list, not a string.

Comment: The CSV parser won't treat `[ghi,jkl]` as a single field. To prevent the comma from being a field specifier, you need to put that field inside quotes.

Comment: What's the format exactly? Are `[` and `]` acting as quote characters here or are they representing a Python list? Either way, I don't think the `csv` module will be able to handle it without pre-processing.

Comment: BTW, welcome back to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips. You can [edit] your question to clarify it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) treats each line as a separate row. Since you want to parse a single line with specific formatting, it might be easier to just read the line as a string and then parse it manually using a regex:

```
import re

with open('file.csv', 'r') as f:
  line = f.readline().strip()
  parts = re.split(r',(?![^\[]*\])', line)
  for i, part in enumerate(parts):
    if part.startswith('[') and part.endswith(']'):
      parts[i] = part[1:-1].split(',')

print(parts)
```

**Output:**

```
['abc', 'def', ['ghi', 'jkl'], 'mno']
```

**Assumes `file.csv` exists with the contents:**

```
abc,def,[ghi,jkl],mno
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you think of this:

```
with open("your_file.csv", "r") as file:
    content = file.read()
    elements = content.strip().split(',')

    result = []
    temp_element = []
    found_list = False

    for element in content.strip().split(','):
        if found_list:
            if "]" in element:
                temp_element.append(element.replace("]",""))
                result.append(temp_element)
                found_list = False
                temp_element = []
        elif "[" in element:
            temp_element.append(element.replace("[",""))
            found_list = True
        else:
            result.append(element)

    print(result)
```

Is brute forcing it but it works.

Comment: I like it! (I upvoted, and someone else downvoted...) When in doubt, brute force it out!

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will use the code above, it is shorter :]